# Changing axis ticks in Matplotlib with multiple connected Boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, axis-labels, xticks

I am plotting a convergence graph and to show deviations from the mean I am using connected boxplots:[image: Connected boxplots]

For some reason Matplotlib forces ticks for each boxplot and I cannot seem to get them removed. My code for the current plot looks something like this:

```
    label = ["" for i in range(160)]
    no_labels = int(np.floor(len(label)/20))
    for i in range(no_labels):
        label[i*20] = str(i*no_samples/no_labels)
    # Weird behaviour for the last label so adding it manually
    label[-1] = no_samples

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.set_xlabel("Samples", labelpad=10)
    ax.set_ylabel("Error (MSE)", labelpad=10)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 0.11)

    ax.boxplot(data, flierprops=flyprops, showcaps=False, 
                boxprops=colorprops, whiskerprops={'color' : 'tab:blue'}, 
                labels=label, patch_artist=True)
```

I have tried multiple ways of manipulating axis ticks which are available in MPL.

1) Trying to let MPL do the work: 
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))`

2) Trying to set ticks manually: `ax.set_xticks([list_of_ticks])`

3) Tried a workaround

```
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(20))    

    # Removing major ticks, setting minor ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', size=0, width=2, direction='in')
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='major', size=5, width=2, direction='in')
```

None of these seemed to work and I am unsure why. I think it may have something to do with my `label` variable but if I don't include it in this way MPL with include an axis lable for every entry which is a mess.

How can I set axis ticks once every 1000 entries in a connected boxplots figure?`

Edit: The input data is a numpy array of shape (15, 160) s.t. there are 160 boxplots plotted of 15 samples each. Example data for 5 boxplots of 3 samples each would look like:

```
       np.random.rand(3,5)

>>>    array([[0.05942481, 0.03408175, 0.84021109, 0.27531937, 0.62428798],
       [0.24658313, 0.77910387, 0.2161348 , 0.39101172, 0.14038211],
       [0.40694432, 0.22979738, 0.87056873, 0.788295  , 0.29337562]])
```

Comment: it would help to understand what the data looks like.  could you include some sample data (maybe generated with random values)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, edited to add sample data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue seems to be that the ticks need to be updated after drawing the main plot, never before.

(Having `ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])` is also quite unusual to work with. The standard way is `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))` which lets matplotlib a bit of flexibility for the whitespace around the plot.)

The code of the question has some missing variables and data, but the following toy example should create something similar:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

no_samples = 8000
x = np.linspace(0, no_samples, 160)
no_labels = int(np.floor(len(x) / 20))
label = [f'{i * no_samples / no_labels:.0f}' for i in range(no_labels+1)]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])

N = 100
data = np.random.normal(np.tile(100 / (x+1000), N), 0.001).reshape(N, -1)

flyprops = {'markersize':0.01}
colorprops = None
ax.boxplot(data, flierprops=flyprops, showcaps=False,
           boxprops=colorprops, whiskerprops={'color': 'tab:blue'},
           patch_artist=True)

ax.set_xlabel("Samples", labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel("Error (MSE)", labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.11)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(x)+1, 20))
ax.set_xticklabels(label)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of setting the tick marks:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=np.random.rand(3,50)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_xlabel("Samples", labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel("Error (MSE)", labelpad=10)

ax.boxplot(data, 
           showcaps=False, 
           whiskerprops={'color' : 'tab:blue'}, 
           patch_artist=True
          )

plt.xticks([10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
           ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"])
```

EDIT:
You can also avoid messing with strings and set the marks like this:

```
N=50
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0, N, num=6), np.linspace(0, N, num=6))
```

See [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) and this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/multiline.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-multiline-py).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple ticks can be acheived in a similar mannar as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3477/319224) (note `data` as transposed numpy array) using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([ np.random.rand(100) for i in range(3) ]).T
plt.boxplot(data)
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], ['mon', 'tue', 'wed'])
```